# Global (window) variable is behaving strangely in Emberjs

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am using Ember-cli in my web app. I have a countdown component to show a countdown timer on UI. Here is my component code.

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    end_time: 0,
    start_time: 0,
    some_id: 0,
    timer: 0, // Show this in UI - {{timer}} Seconds

    init: function() {
        this._super();
        let end_time = this.get("end_time"),  // 1479476467693
            start_time = this.get("start_time"), // 1479476381491
            some_id = this.get("some_id");
        let wait_time = Math.floor((end_time - start_time)/1000);
        this.set('timer', wait_time);
        let timerName = "timer_" + some_id;
        let _self = this;
        window.initTimer.someTimer[timerName] = setInterval(function() {
            _self.set('timer', wait_time);
            if(wait_time <= 0) {
                clearInterval(window.initTimer.someTimer[timerName]);
            }
            wait_time --;
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

This component works fine, if I add this to a single route.

Now, I have added this component to both parent route and child (/:ID) route, since I need to show the component on both templates. In the child (/:ID) template, I have a button to clear the timer. So I have added this code for that button action.

```
buttonAction: function(some_id) {
            let timerName = "timer_" + some_id;
            clearInterval(window.initTimer.someTimer[timerName]);
        }
```

Strangely, when the buttonAction is called, the timer on the child template alone is cleared. The timer on parent template keeps running. But both the timer are assigned to a single global variable (`window.initTimer.someTimer`) and should be cleared when I run `clearInterval()`.

Is there any solution for clearing the timer on both parent route and child route on click of a button, which resides on child template? Couldn't figure out what magic Ember is playing with global variables!!

Answer (score 1):

Ember is doing no magic here, but your code is *much* to complicated!

The interesting question is from where `some_id` comes. If its not the same for both then with which one are you calling `buttonAction`?

Assume you have the ids `one` and `two`. Then you have the two intervals at `window.initTimer.someTimer.timer_one` and `window.initTimer.someTimer.timer_two`. Now if you clear `window.initTimer.someTimer.timer_one` why should `window.initTimer.someTimer.timer_two` be cleared as well? Well, its not, and thats why your code is not working.

Assume you only have one id, lets call is `theOnlyOne` for both timers.
Then the `init` hook of the second component will reassign `window.initTimer.someTimer.timer_theOnlyOne`, and so only this second component can be resetted when you call `buttonAction`. Then thats why your code is not working.

---

So what should you do now? First, you *really* should stop using the global object! There are so much better ways to do this in the ember ecosystem.

For your timers you should check out [ember-concurrency](http://ember-concurrency.com/).

If you want to use a global state you should use a [`service`](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.9.0/applications/services/). However I don't recommend this for your problem, because it's against the DDAU principle. However to tell you whats the right way to do what you want to do we need to understand why you have this timers, how they are related and why you want to cancel them both with one click. Probably you would have some timer state outside of the components and pass it down to the components. Maybe a `util` can be helpful. But this really depends on your use-case.

Comment: The id is same for both the routes. You have correctly pointed out. The issue is due to reassigning. I missed that part totally. Thanks.